# Partially parallel loops using openmp tasks

Tags: c, multithreading, parallel-processing, task, openmp

**Prerequisites:**

- parallel engine: OpenMP 3.1+ (can be OpenMP 4.0 if needed)
- parallel constructs: OpenMP tasks
- compiler: gcc 4.9.x (supports OpenMP 4.0)

**Input:**

- C code with loops
- loop have cross-iteration data dependency(ies): “i+1“ iteration needs data from “i” iteration (only such kind of dependency, nothing else)
- loop body can be partially dependent
- loop cannot be split in two loops; loop body should remain solid
- anything reasonable can be added to loop or loop body function definition

**Code sample:**

*(Here conf/config/configData variables are used for illustration purposes only, the main interest is within value/valueData variables.)*

```
void loopFunc(const char* config, int* value)
{
    int conf;
    conf = prepare(config);         // independent, does not change “config”
    *value = process(conf, *value); // dependent, takes prev., produce next
    return;
}

int main()
{
    int N = 100;
    char* configData;           // never changes
    int valueData = 0;          // initial value
    …
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        loopFunc(configData, &valueData);
    }
    …
}
```

**Need to:**

- parallelise loop using omp tasks (omp for / omp sections cannot be used)
- “prepare” functions should be executed in parallel with other “prepare” or “process” functions
- “process” functions should be ordered according to data dependency

**What have been proposed and implemented:**

- define integer flag
- assign to it a number of first iteration
- every iteration when it needs data waits for flag to be equal to it’s iteration
- update flag value when data for next iteration is ready

Like this:

*(I reminds that conf/config/configData variables are used for illustration purposes only, the main interest is within value/valueData variables.)*

```
void loopFunc(const char* config, int* value, volatile int *parSync, int iteration)
{
    int conf;
    conf = prepare(config);         // independent, do not change “config”
    while (*parSync != iteration)   // wait for previous to be ready
    {
        #pragma omp taskyield
    }
    *value = process(conf, *value); // dependent, takes prev., produce next
    *parSync = iteration + 1;       // inform next about readiness
    return;
}

int main()
{
    int N = 100;
    char* configData;           // never changes
    int valueData = 0;          // initial value
    volatile int parallelSync = 0;
    …
    omp_set_num_threads(5);
    #pragma omp parallel
    #pragma omp single
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        #pragma omp task shared(configData, valueData, parallelSync) firstprivate(i)
            loopFunc(configData, &valueData, &parallelSync, i);
    }
    #pragma omp taskwait
    …
}
```

**What happened:**

It fails. :)

**The reason** was that openmp task occupies openmp thread.
For example, if we define 5 openmp threads (as in the code above).

- “For” loop generates 100 tasks.
- OpenMP runtime assign 5 arbitrary tasks to 5 threads and starts these tasks.

If there will be no task with i=0 among started tasks (it happens time to time), executing tasks wait forever, occupy threads forever and the task with i=0 never being started.

***What's next?***

*I have no other ideas how to implement the required mode of computation.*

**Current solution**

*Thanks for the idea to @parallelgeek below*

```
int main()
{
    int N = 10;
    char* configData;           // never changes
    int valueData = 0;          // initial value
    volatile int parallelSync = 0;
    int workers;
    volatile int workingTasks = 0;
    ...
    omp_set_num_threads(5);
    #pragma omp parallel
    #pragma omp single
    {
        workers = omp_get_num_threads()-1;  // reserve 1 thread for task generation

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            while (workingTasks >= workers)
            {
                #pragma omp taskyield
            }

            #pragma omp atomic update
                workingTasks++;

            #pragma omp task shared(configData, valueData, parallelSync, workingTasks) firstprivate(i)
            {
                loopFunc(configData, &valueData, &parallelSync, i);

                #pragma omp atomic update
                    workingTasks--;
            }
        }
        #pragma omp taskwait
    }
}
```

Comment: Let's see, you declare **char* configData;**, then you pass it to **loopFunc()** inside **loopFunc()** you pass it to process(conf, *value);**. **Q:** what exactly is(does) process() ?

Comment: @Michi: Here conf/config/configData variables are used for illustration purposes only, the main interest is within value/valueData variables. Updated the post. "Prepare" illustrates value-independent function which takes time but does not interact with other iterations. "Process" illustrates function that takes data from previous iteration and produces new value for the next iteration,

Comment: @Gilles. "int &xxx", AFAIK, can be used only in C++? I need to be C-compatible... Thus "flush" seems to be impossible at all, as if omp does not allows to flush dereferenced values like flush(*parSync)...

Comment: Another thing that bugs me is that the standard says "Whenever a thread reaches a task scheduling point, the implementation **may** cause it to perform a task switch, beginning or resuming execution of a different task bound to the current team". No obligations here, so your code's behaviour is implementation define anyway, isn't it? But just in case, I would also play with the `OMP_WAIT_POLICY` to set it to `PASSIVE` in case it allows for better task scheduling...

Comment: @Gilles, yes, it's behaviour of the solution is unpredictable and this is the main problem. That's why I raise the question here..

Comment: How about removing volatile? You've provided enough information to the compiler that workingTasks is a shared variable, so IMHO it should not apply it's black magic anymore. What does OpenMP standard says about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. AFAIK volatiles don't prevent hardware reordering, that's why you
   could end up with a mess in memory, because data is not written yet,
   while flag is already seen by the consuming thread as `true`.
2. That's why little piece of advise: use C11 atomics instead in order to ensure visibility of data. As I can see, gcc 4.9 supports c11 [C11Status in GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/C11Status)
3. You could try to divide generated tasks to groups by K tasks, where `K == ThreadNum` and start generating subsequent task (after the tasks in the first group are generated) only after any of running tasks is finished. Thus you have an **invariant** that *each time you have only K tasks running and scheduled on K threads*.
4. Intertask dependencies could also be met by using atomic flags from C11.